Is there a complete list of world.beforeEvents and world.afterEvents current for the latest stable version of the @minecraft/server module?
The official Script APIs documentation at Microsoft Learn has a full list of every @minecraft/server property and method, which allows selecting between either the stable or experimental version of the module.
However, while I've found the site to be generally reliable and kept current, this particular page lists many .before- and .afterEvents which are still experimental under the "Minecraft Bedrock Stable APIs" view. (As one such example, the playerInteractWithBlock events are not actually defined as of version 1.10.0, although they are listed under the dropdown for both stable and experimental versions).
When you try to use these in your main.js file with the script module's version number in manifest.json set to the latest release version, an error is displayed saying the method is undefined. (The same methods work correctly if the manifest.json version number is set to the latest beta, without making any changes to the script file.)
The Bedrock Wiki sometimes has more detailed information on specific topics, but in this case it just redirects back to the official list.
Is there anywhere I can find a list of only the world.beforeEvents and world.afterEvents which are available without using an experimental version?

Note: As of @minecraft/server 1.15.0 (stable), playerInteractWithBlock has been added and is usable!

Here is the full list, which is current as of @minecraft/server version 1.15.0:

world.beforeEvents

explosion
itemUse
itemUseOn
playerBreakBlock
entityRemove
playerInteractWithBlock
playerInteractWithEntity
playerLeave
playerGameModeChange
effectAdd
weatherChange
worldInitialize


world.afterEvents

worldInitialize
gameRuleChange
weatherChange
buttonPush
leverAction
playerPlaceBlock
blockExplode
explosion
playerBreakBlock
entityLoad
entitySpawn
dataDrivenEntityTrigger
effectAdd
projectileHitEntity
projectileHitBlock
entityHitEntity
entityHitBlock
entityHurt
entityHealthChanged
entityDie
entityRemove
itemStartUseOn
itemUseOn
itemUse
itemStopUseOn
itemStartUse
itemCompleteUse
itemReleaseUse
itemStopUse
playerJoin
playerSpawn
playerLeave
playerGameModeChange
playerDimensionChange
playerInputPermissionCategoryChange
playerInteractWithEntity
playerInteractWithBlock
pistonActivate
pressurePlatePush
pressurePlatePop
targetBlockHit
tripWireTrip
playerEmote


An accurate list of all available world.before- and .afterEvents can always be obtained by first going to Settings -> Creator -> Enable Content Log GUI, then adding the following to your behavior pack's main.js file:
world.afterEvents.playerSpawn.subscribe(event => {
    for (var ev in world.beforeEvents) {
        console.warn(ev);
    }
    console.warn("--------------------------------------");
    for (var ev in world.afterEvents) {
        console.warn(ev);
    }
});

Next, launch a world with that behavior pack active. As soon as it loads, you should see text overlaid on the screen which will be the last few items in the list of event names. To view the complete list, go back to Settings -> Creator -> Content Log History, and you will get a scrollable list of every current .before- and .afterEvent, separated by a line of dashes.
